# BitmapImage Synchronously using SetSource but for a local (project) file (or, how to get a local project file as a Stream)

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am trying to synchronously load a bitmap file into memory at a certain point in my application, and read that SetSource() will do just that (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/swick/archive/2011/04/07/image-tips-for-windows-phone-7.aspx).

However, I am used to using the UriSource property which works great for local files:

```
BitmapImage backgroundImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Background.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

However, the SetSource function takes a "Stream", not a Uri, and I need to load a local project file. Can you please tell me what the best way to do this is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you do this:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("/YourProjectName;component/Background.png", UriKind.Relative);
StreamResourceInfo resourceInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
bmp.SetSource(resourceInfo.Stream);
```

Comment: That's awesome, thanks, I literally spent over 2 hours trying to figure that out and ended up nowhere!

Comment: I keep getting a null reference. My Uri must not be correct. I have the image in my base directory, am I missing something?

Comment: Got it working. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10949571/how-to-change-the-background-of-a-grid-to-an-image-in-wp7-silverlight. I suppose I still don't understand the construction or your Uri.